# Как загрузить файл в формате .json с сервера?

Tags: php, json

Возникла проблема с загрузкой файла в формате .json с локального сервера – вместо загрузки в том же окне браузера открывается PHP-скрипт с HTML-вёрсткой.
Сначала производится выгрузка данных из таблицы в файл table_name.json на сервере, а затем его необходимо сразу передать на загрузку через браузер.

Пример кода:

```
function CreateJSON($table, $data)
            {
                $file = fopen("{$table}.json", 'w');
                fwrite($file, json_encode($data));

                fclose($file);

                $file = "{$table}.json";                
                header('Content-Desposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Content-Type: application/json');                
            }
```

Использую XAMPP.

P.S. использовал те же заголовки при загрузке .csv с сервера, однако там полёт прошёл нормально и файл загрузился.

Comment: `<?php` в начале забыли?

Comment: @teran не забыл

Comment: Код покажете? Включая имя файла с расширением

Comment: @AntonShchyrov обновил. Добавил в описание информацию по нему.